# Keep TableViewRow selected in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium

I'm developing a simple product catalog in Titanium and I have a TableView with the list of products and a product detail view to view the selected product. What I want to do is have the selected product visibly selected in the TableView.

Titanium defaults to deselecting rows with animation so the selection color fades out whenever a row is selected.

This is how my app looks like now:
[image: This is how my app looks like now]

This is how I want it to look:
[image: This is how I want it to look]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
// Create table view data object
var data = [
    {title:'Row 1', hasChild:true, color:'red', selectedColor:'#fff'},
    {title:'Row 2', hasDetail:true, color:'green', selectedColor:'#fff'},
    {title:'Row 3', hasCheck:true, color:'blue', selectedColor:'#fff'},
    {title:'Row 4', color:'orange', selectedColor:'#fff'}
];

// Create table view and set allowSelection to true
var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:data,
    allowsSelection:true  // This should do the trick
});

// Select the 4th row
tableview.selectRow(3);

// Add table view to the current window
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(tableview);
```